# How to enable Server side rendering in Next 13?

Tags: reactjs, caching, next.js, fetch, server-side-rendering

I am new to Next 13 syntax, and I have a problem with enabling SSR in dynamic routes. Here is how my [id]/page.tsx file looks like:

```
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'
const getData = async (id: string): Promise<EducationalInstitution | null> => {
  console.log('get data')
  try {
    const sessionCookie = cookies().get('Custom.Session')?.value;
    const sessionData = await getServerSession(authOptions);

    const response = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_API_URL}/educationalInstitutions/${id}`, {
      method: 'GET',
      // @ts-ignore
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Cookie': `Custom.Session=${sessionCookie}`
      },
      cache: 'no-store'
    });

    if (!response.ok) {
      return null;
    }

    const responseData = await response.json();
    return responseData;
  } catch (e: any) {
    return null;
  }
};
```

I noticed,that if I try to open this page via , it makes getData request only once(on first render). After that, it returns cached data, even if there are changes in DB. I also tried to add

```
export const revalidated = 0
```

But it did not help. When I refresh this page with ctrl+r, I can see console.log('get data') in my console, and new changes from DB, but not when I am navigation to this page with .

I know, that in previous versions, all I needed to do, is to use gerServerSideProps() functions, if I wanted to to SSR page on every request, but I do not understand, how to achieve it in Next 13.